# Android TV views focus issue while navigating through D-pad in the remote

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have an Android TV App where I need the views in the menu bar to be focusable (with a blue background or something) while we press D-pad buttons through TV remote. I put a `StateListDrawable` for the views to show a blue border while the view got focus with direction pad.

Here is the drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_border" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

And heres what happened after I pressed the down button in the remote.

[image]

All Views till the current focused button have focus as I press down in the remote everytime, I want only the current focus with remote to have focus. How can I solve this? Am I missing something?

TIA.